# Extra dash inserted by listings package in text mode

Tags: listings

The code below is rendered to this:

```
              location/-
counter.
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\hspace{0.85\linewidth} location/counter

\end{document}
```

Apparently the culprit is the `listings` package because w/o loading it the problem disappears (with various `hspace` settings that push for hyphenation).

Thus my question: ?! ;)

pdflatex version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) and listings 1.6.

Comment: Thanks egreg. I wonder why it did not show up when I was searching for it :/ I wonder even more if it ever was fixed upstream...